# when calling GetProductInfo gets an PInvokeStackImbalance error [VB.NET]

Tags: vb.net

I am testing this on Win 7 Ultimate and it generates an error:

> PInvokeStackImbalance was detected Message: A call to PInvoke function
>   'WindowsApplication1!WindowsApplication1.Form1::GetProductInfo' has
>   unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke
>   signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that
>   the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match
>   the target unmanaged signature.

```
Public Class Form1


   Private Const PRODUCT_STARTER As Integer = &HB                            'Starter
   Private Const PRODUCT_HOME_BASIC As Integer = &H2                         'Home Basic
   Private Const PRODUCT_HOME_BASIC_N As Integer = &H5                       'Home Basic N
   Private Const PRODUCT_HOME_PREMIUM As Integer = &H3                       'Home Premium
   Private Const PRODUCT_HOME_PREMIUM_N As Integer = &H1A                    'Home Premium N
   Private Const PRODUCT_BUSINESS As Integer = &H6                           'Business
   Private Const PRODUCT_BUSINESS_N As Integer = &H10                        'Business N
   Private Const PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE As Integer = &H4                         'Enterprise
   Private Const PRODUCT_ENTERPRISE_N As Integer = &H1B                      'Enterprise N
   Private Const PRODUCT_ULTIMATE As Integer = &H1                           'Ultimate
   Private Const PRODUCT_ULTIMATE_N As Integer = &H1C                        'Ultimate N

   Private Declare Function GetProductInfo Lib "kernel32" _
      (ByVal dwOSMajorVersion As Long, ByVal dwOSMinorVersion As Long, _
      ByVal dwSpMajorVersion As Long, ByVal dwSpMinorVersion As Long, _
      ByRef pdwReturnedProductType As Long) As Long

   Public Function GetOSProduct() As String
      Dim os As OperatingSystem = Environment.OSVersion
      Dim prodType As Long
      GetOSProduct = ""
      If GetProductInfo(os.Version.Major, os.Version.Minor, 0, 0, prodType) Then
         Select Case prodType
            Case PRODUCT_ULTIMATE
               GetOSProduct = "Ultimate"
            Case PRODUCT_ULTIMATE_N
               GetOSProduct = "Ultimate N"
            Case Else
               GetOSProduct = "unknown"
         End Select
      End If
   End Function

   Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
      MsgBox(GetOSProduct)
   End Sub
End Class
```

can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

just replace **Long** (used in VB6) with **Integer** (used in VB.NET)